# Find object by key in array of object

Tags: javascript

Hello this is array of objects

```
  const raceId = '1004'
  const array =  [
    {
      '1004': { brackets: { '18': [Object], '19': [Object], '20': [Object] } }
    },
    {
      '999': { brackets: { '1': [Object], '2': [Object], '3': [Object] } }
    }
  ]
```

So i am trying to return just a

```
{ brackets: { '18': [Object], '19': [Object], '20': [Object] } }
```

I have tried to use reduce(), map(), find() but not getting desired output. For example i have tried.

```
const reduced = raceScoringConfigGroups.reduce((acc, key) => {
   if (Object.keys(key)[0] === raceId) {
     return key[raceId]
   }
  }, {})
```

But for some reason getting undefined, can someone help me just a little bit, not sure what i am doing wrong. I don't like solutions with forEach or for loops, trying to write oneliner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you return in the `reduce()` callback is used as the accumulator in the next iteration. Since you don't return anything when the key doesn't match `raceId`, your code will only work if the matching key is the last element of the array.

Use `find()` rather than `reduce()`, and then get the property from that.

```
const found = raceScoringConfigGroups.find(el => el[raceId]);
const reduced = found?.[raceId];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

`const result = array.filter(el => Object.keys(el) === raceId)[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Well to a certain extent it is working as a loop because if you put a console.log before the return key[raceId] you will see that it first returns a value and then undefined.

I don't know if it's close to what you want to do but this is a way to find the object too

```js
const findIt = array.find( item => Object.keys(item)[0] === raceId);
console.log(findIt)
console.log(findIt['1004'])
```